# Select first <p> tag can anyone tell what is xpath of below code?

Tags: xpath

```html
<div class="main-banner"><img alt="Health and Safety In Care" height="291px" width="650px" class="img-responsive" height="291px" Width="650px" src="images/Care Safety.jpg" /></div>  

<p>It is a legal requirement that those in the care sector must have sufficient health and safety training to ensure the safety of both staff and patients.</p>
<p>The below range of health and safety courses specialise in handling different equipment and scenarios often encountered in the care sector. Our courses boast accreditation from the CIEH and HABC, and are designed to fulfil recommendations made by the CQC.</p>
```

> select `<p>` tag for xpath after below `<div>` tag that contain
>   `main-banner` class.

```
<div class="main-banner"><img alt="Health and Safety In Care" height="291px" width="650px" class="img-responsive" height="291px" Width="650px" src="images/Care Safety.jpg" /></div>  

<p>It is a legal requirement that those in the care sector must have sufficient health and safety training to ensure the safety of both staff and patients.</p>
<p>The below range of health and safety courses specialise in handling different equipment and scenarios often encountered in the care sector. Our courses boast accreditation from the CIEH and HABC, and are designed to fulfil recommendations made by the CQC.</p></div>
```

Comment: IS this for selenium

Comment: no, actually i want to show <p> tag after the <div> tag which contain class="main-banner" only

Comment: Ok actuallly I think you are using selenium

Comment: so.. do u know what is the xpath of above code?

Comment: Try this //p[contains(text(),'It is a legal requirement that those')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select the **1**st `<p>` node right after the `<div>` node with `class="main-banner"`:

```
(//div[@class="main-banner"]/following-sibling::p)[1]
```

**----------**

In case if the crucial `<div>` node has multiple items within class attribute like `class="cont baseline main-banner"` use the following *xpath* expression:

```
(//div[contains(@class,"main-banner")]/following-sibling::p)[1]
```

Comment: @SandeepSuthar, *not working* - never was and never will be the actual description of the problem. You should provide details, errors, messages

Comment: @SandeepSuthar, First, your input is invalid: I had to make some corrections to deal with valid xml content. XML validator will immediately throw "the img tag already has `height` tag" - cause you got duplicated attributes in your `img` tag. So, I admit that the solution works fine with VALID xml/html input content. And here's a test link : http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=7bf28736-6cab-4a35-809d-a43fca24b6ae-xpath#.WcuX_8Zx2Uk. Second, after you made your input valid - check your syntax for errors (human factor)

Comment: expect `<img>` tag focus on `<p>`..and itz not working and yes xpath is correct but result is not showing :) .thanx brother for help.

Answer (score 0):

**xpath :**

```
  //div[@class="main-banner"]/following-sibling::p [1]
```